# How to prevent the CONCATENATE function from producing double quotes around character string?

Tags: excel, indexing, concatenation, double, quotes

I'm pasting this formula in a cell to create a reference to another workbook:

```
=-INDEX(CONCATENATE("'";"C:\Users\Me\Projects\pythonProj\[";$AZ$1;".xlsx]";"Feuil1";"'";"!$1:$1048576");14-AZ$4;18)
```

where:

- cell AZ1 contains a character string which is the name of the
  Excel file I'm referring to.
- cell AZ4 contains a number.

However:

```
CONCATENATE("'";"C:\Users\Me\Projects\pythonProj\[";$AZ$1;".xlsx]";"Feuil1";"'";"!$1:$1048576")
```

produces the following result:

```
"'C:\Users\Me\Projects\pythonProj\[Filename.xlsx]Feuil1'$1:$1048576"
```

which prevents the INDEX function from generating an output.

I would like to get rid of the double quotes `"` that appear at both ends of the string, but whatever I try doesn't work. Replacing the CONCATENATE function by &-separated strings doesn't yield the correct result either.

Comment: You cannot create a reference like that. You'd need to wrap it in `INDIRECT` but that only works with open workbooks.

Comment: Use `CONCATENATE("'"...` instead of `CONCATENATE("'";"` but you may need `indirect()` function as @Rory suggested.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Rory. Is there another way to get around this issue? I initially found that using the command INDEX('C:\Users\Me\Projects\pythonProj\[Filename.xlsx]Feuil1'!$1:$1048576);14-AZ$4;18) got me the right result but I would like the filename to be easily modifiable (without having to rely on the Excel search and replace feature).

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by "open workbook"? Does it mean that the referenced workbook should be open in an another Excel instance?

Comment: No, it has to be open in the **same** instance, or `INDIRECT` will not work. There is no other option without code (search for Harlan Grove's Pull function for example)